How to highlight a specific IME in ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS for android
When I call the android settings menu to enable my input method, I would like the menu to flash to highlight the correct item in the list for my keyboard.  I saw this happen when installing another keyboard, but can't seem to find the correct code/identifier.
Currently my code looks like this.
  val imeIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
  imeIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_INPUT_METHOD_ID,"com.storyfeet.keyseypeasy")
  startActivity(imeIntent);

It works, in that I can turn on the keyboard, but it doesn't highlight the correct row.
I assume I have to get to the correct ID for my service:
        <service
            android:name=".KeyseyPeasy"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/method" />
        </service>


I have also tried:
".KeyseyPeasy"
"com.storyfeet.keyseypeasy.KeyseyPeasy"
and a few other variations

This suggests that it is the getId() value from InputMethodInfo, but it is unclear to me how to get your own ID.

The ID is defined as ComponentName#flattenToShortString(): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodInfo#getId(). You can assemble that manually – e.g., "com.storyfeet.keyseypeasy/.KeyseyPeasy" - or create a ComponentName first, if you'd rather; e.g., ComponentName(context, KeyseyPeasy::class.java).flattenToShortString().
